# Using ArcGIS Online feature service attribute table dynamically in Excel

Tags: arcgis-online, excel, dynamic-tables

I've been trying to find a solution for a while now that will allow me to view a feature service in Excel without having to export. I'm aware of the ESRI Office add-in, however, this is only to upload/update data, and not to import data.

This will save me lots of time every month summarizing data from exports. I'd like to have it auto-fill into a template.

Answer (score 1):

In short: you can't. If it's a hosted layer in AGOL / Enterprise, you can't view a *dynamic* table outside of some GIS software, or something you build yourself.

That said, it would be quite simple to create a script which uses the [ArcGIS Python API](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/api-reference/) to export that layer to an excel file, then schedule that script to run, overwriting the file at regular intervals.

```
from arcgis import GIS, GeoAccessor

gis = GIS('portal-url')

fl = gis.content.get('layer-itemID').layers[0]

df = GeoAccessor.from_layer(fl)

# Reshape and sort your dataframe to fit the column name / formatting you need

df.to_excel('output-filepath')
```